# LaunchOptions.DesiredRemainingView - Split screen launched app

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

I am trying to open files in their native application from my app.

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.getFileAsync("downloads\\" + fileName).then(
    function (file) {
        var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
        options.displayApplicationPicker = true;
        options.desiredRemainingView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewSizePreference.useHalf;

        Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file, options).then(
            function (success) {
                if (success) {
                    //File launched
                } else {
                    // File launch failed
                }
            });
    });
```

I tried using the [LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298314) to make sure every launch would have the apps split screen (50/50) and the native apps still open at whatever size they default to. Reader(50%), Photos(70%).

In the Windows Dev Center - Windows Store apps there is a sample for launching that includes the different enumerations of [DesiredRemainingView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298314) and none of the enumerations worked when I built the downloaded sample.

Are there other options (LauncherOptions) that I need to modify/set?

Comment: Are you working on a big enough resolution? Can you get other apps to show at 50% or 500px?

Comment: According to MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298314) says that there is no real guarantee that you can control the size. It appears to be the app you are launching that controls the initial size.